# How can I do object tracking inside ROS2 node?

Tags: python, ros, yolo, ros2, object-tracking

I would like to track objects in the video that had taken from another node as a sensor_msgs.msg. I managed to detect the objects but I need to track the detected objects as well. I tried to use github repos enable to track objects but it is only used from terminal. But i need to run tracking inside the callback func. How is it possible? Do you have any suggestions like github repos, youtube videos or sampe code etc.?

Comment: There are a lot of repos like: https://github.com/yehengchen/Object-Detection-and-Tracking or https://github.com/wmuron/motpy .

Comment: First link is used for ROS, not ROS2. For the second link, i could not understand how can I use inside the ROS2 callback function. I have already tried to use deepSORT and strongSORT but my problem was inserting this algorithm inside ROS2 node.